# The request bounding box has zero area?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have published directory of shapefiles in GeoServer in which one shapefile has only one feature (point).  While previewing the layer GeoServer WMS error says that `The request bounding box has Zero area`. I had so many shapefiles with single feature (point).

How can avoid this Zero area error in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the bounding boxes of the layer manually with the GeoServer admin utility to cover some reasonable area. The BBOX that is automatically calculated from data for a single point is also just a point and that's the reason for your trouble. You can either feed a new Lat/Lon Bounding Box directly or alternatively enter numbers into Native Bounding Box and press then "Compute from native bounds" link for updating the Lat/Lon coordinates.

If there are lots of layers and bounding boxes to edit it is best to learn to use the REST API. How to do it is much too wide question to be answered here. I refer to GeoServer documentation http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html. To start with, this request reads the layer settings for topp:states with REST.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/states_shapefile/featuretypes/states.xml
```

For changing the bounding boxes the corresponding elements can be PUT back with REST.

```
 <nativeBoundingBox>
    <minx>-124.73142200000001</minx>
    <maxx>-66.969849</maxx>
    <miny>24.955967</miny>
    <maxy>49.371735</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </nativeBoundingBox>
  <latLonBoundingBox>
    <minx>-124.731422</minx>
    <maxx>-66.969849</maxx>
    <miny>24.955967</miny>
    <maxy>49.371735</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </latLonBoundingBox>
```

Alternatively it is possible to edit the xml files inside data_dir manually but that is not really recommended because of all the mess that wrong edits can make. Anyway, for example for adjusting the "topp:states" layer find xml file from `data_dir\workspaces\topp\states_shapefile\states\featuretype.xml`.

Comment: How can do automatically? I have huge data?

Comment: Having huge amount of layers with only one point on each feels like an odd idea for me but I have seen that odd ideas may have a reason. Learn to use REST then. It is complicated but you will learn it.